# Strange clicking noise related to water supply

Tags: water, noise, pressure

I have experienced a strange clicking noise coming from under my house. Not the banging noise I read about in other posts - this is not the sound of a pipe hitting a wall. It's very hard to trace as it lasts only 3 seconds or so most of the time. One time I got lucky and was under the house while it was still going. It sounded like it was coming from the water pressure regulator and indeed there was a difference in vibration of the pipe on one side of the regulator vs the other. I tested the pressure and sure enough - it was at 125, which meant the pressure regular was no longer regulating the pressure. So I had it replaced. I thought the problem was solved. It did make a difference - the noise is no longer loud enough to wake me - but it does continue to happen now and then, albeit at a lower volume. Any ideas what could be causing this and how it's related to the pressure regulator or water pressure in general? The new pressure regulator is working fine - I have it tuned to about 75.

Comment: Are there any definable variables? Like, does it happen only when water is flowing, only when not flowing? Or is it totally random? When did you first hear it; like is it fairly new? Were there any plumbing changes that coincide with its beginning that you can think of? What type of water supply pipe do you have? Do you have a hot water recirculation system? Water softener? Can you tell if it is only on the hot/cold pipe(s)? Do you have an expansion tank on your water heater line?

Comment: Oddly, there is no connection with water flowing and the noise. It can happen any time of the day or night, even when I haven't touched a faucet in hours. I suspect the failure of the original pressure regulator may have coincided with the noise beginning, but that's just a guess. Water supply is copper. No recirc system or softener. No expansion tank. It appeared to be centered around the pressure regulator, but the sound stopped seconds after I arrived at the regulator the one time it lasted long enough for me to follow it, so I could be wrong.

Comment: I found a recording I made of the old (louder) noise one of the rare times it lasted more than 3 seconds:
https://www.madmartian.com/special/Noise1excerpt.mp3
Note that it has two apparent speeds - the faster speed partway through the recording is more typical. No water was running at or near-previous to the recording.

Comment: that could be the sound of your water meter running.

Comment: The water meter is at the street between my house and my neighbors. Not necessarily ruled out as the pipe itself could carry the sound from the meter to the pressure regulator, so I will investigate that. Thanks.